# unable to cast object of type 'system.int32' to type 'system.int32[] '

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I get the above error in the fourth line. How do I (assuming I have to) convert the value to have the same datatype on both sides?

```
dsOrderList = objResult.ds
        For Each drow As DataRow In dsOrderList.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim objOrder As New Orders
            objOrder.OrderID = drow("OrderID")
            objOrder.CustomerID = drow("CustomerID")
            objOrder.EmployeeID = drow("EmployeeID")
```

Comment: Is it the property Orders.OrderID an array of ints?

Comment: Good catch Steve... probably the problem, although some casting may be good too.

Comment: yes its an array, so what needs to be done?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly with this array ? do you want to append the value to the array, replace a value at a specific index in the array ? Anyway looking at a book or a tutorial on programming or VB.NET may be a good idea seeing the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are string a Value into Array Of Integer, there must be an array or provide element of array

```
dsOrderList = objResult.ds
    For Each drow As DataRow In dsOrderList.Tables(0).Rows
        Dim objOrder As New Orders
        objOrder.OrderID(0) = drow("OrderID") '0 is Element of Order ID
        objOrder.CustomerID = drow("CustomerID")
        objOrder.EmployeeID = drow("EmployeeID")
```

or

```
dsOrderList = objResult.ds
    For Each drow As DataRow In dsOrderList.Tables(0).Rows
        Dim objOrder As New Orders
        objOrder.OrderID =  {drow("OrderID")}
        objOrder.CustomerID = drow("CustomerID")
        objOrder.EmployeeID = drow("EmployeeID")
```

> update

if the element of objOrder.OrderID is nothing then use

```
objOrder.OrderID = new int() {drow{"OrderID"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the values from your dataRow to int, string, etc values before assigning it to another variable, whose type is probably int

Comment: like doing typecasting... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5044/Cheat-Sheet-Casting-in-VB-NET-and-C , but see the comment from Steve on your question, it's probably the cause of your problem...

Comment: its an array..!(as in multiple values)